# All the if statements running in c#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have some code below which is a URL Parser and the if statement doesn't work instead of executing the code when it is true it executes all the code in all the if statements.

```
    public static class var
    { //Global variables
        public static string stre = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(Environment.CommandLine);
        public static string[] str = stre.Remove(stre.Length - 1).Split(new string[] { "cmd:" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
    public CMD()
    { //I suppose this class runs first so all my is statements are here
        AClsMsgBox.Show("Parsing...", "CMD Parser", 1000); //msgbox
        if (var.stre.Length > 5) { InitializeComponent();} //This executes even if I type "cmd:" which should trigger the statement below. (Always executes) This should run when typing "cmd:echo a command"
        else if (var.stre.Length == 4) { Process.Start("cmd.exe"); } //This should run when typing "cmd:"(Never execute)
        else { AClsMsgBox.Show("This is a URL Parser use it by typing 'cmd:<command>' in the URL adress bar field of a browsers.","CMD Parser",60000); } //Always executes
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stra = var.str[1].Replace("&", "&&");
        label1.Text += stra;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("cmd.exe", " /k " + var.str[1]);
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
}
```

This is C# GUI so I am running `InitializeComponent()` only if I need to display the rest of buttons and stuff. (I think it should stop the GUI)

> And there are no errors! But appear after building the code.

> On running debugger:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
HResult=0x80131508
Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source=CMD Parser GUI
StackTrace:
at CMD_Parser_GUI.CMD.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\bat\CMD Parser GUI\Form1.cs:line 61
line 61 is "string stra = var.str[1].Replace("&", "&&");"
```

Comment: Have you debugged it to see what's really going on?

Comment: It says exeption Thrown  Index was out of bounds of array and it highlights this line `string stra = var.str[1].Replace("&", "&&");` it looks fine to me.

Comment: This code is so convoluted it's perhaps unsurprising that there are bugs.. but I think it's reasonable to say in an argument over whether a string is longer than 5 chars where you say it isn't and c# behaves as if it is, that you're the one that is mistaken.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with your IF statement, it's actually an error in your code. So what does the variable `var` contain? Clearly there is something wrong with that code, most likely due to variable values

Comment: OT `var` is a reserved word. Please use a more descriptive name in the future

Comment: How many items does `var.str` contain? Apparently not more than 1. Note that the index of the first item is 0

Comment: I'm seeing `if () {} if () {} else {}`. Did you intend to have an `else if` in the middle?

Comment: var is a class that I've used to define global variables.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm not to sure about that what's the difference. Well if the first `if` is true when the input is "cmd:echo command" then why does the else also activate?

Comment: Because the first if is unrelated to the others. The first if may run or it may not. But either the second if or the else will always run.

Comment: Now it works better the `else` doesn't get triggered when input is "cmd:echo command" (by replacing 2nd if with else if). But if I type "cmd:" it doesn't trigger the 2nd `else if`. (Also replaced `var` with `gvar` just in case).

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm trying to make a URL parser so when I open the url "cmd:<command>" it should give me a prompt asking me if i want to run the command, also if url "cmd:" is opened it should launch cmd.exe without a prompt. And if I click on the `exe` file it should advise me how to use it. (I've written it all in the if and else statements).

Comment: You mean you want to be able to type `cmd:format%20c%3a` into a browser address bar and destroy your computer?

Comment: Like that but without destruction! Thats why I have a confirmation prompt.

Comment: Related: [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yeah It will be throwing that error cause there are no parameters but if there are no parameters it should run the code in the `else` statement and should not run the rest of the code but it does and how do I stop that? Cause if there are no parameters `else` should be triggered if parameter is "cmd:" `else if` should be triggered if parameter is "cmd:<commmand>" `if` should be triggered and then only the rest of code.

Comment: What *actually is* the value of `var.stre.Length`? It might start with the full pathname of the executable - way more than 5 chars. See [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline?view=net-5.0#examples)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes it does begin with the path thats. So thats giving the problem all along.

Comment: FYI the [Main method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) (=startpoint of your application) might be a better place to intercept commandline arguments than some Form